# REST API for forgotten username

Tags: json, rest

I'm adding a new REST service to our API, and wanted to canvas a few opinions on the best REST API. The service is used to retrieve the user's email address in case they have forgotten what their username is.  The service requires three parameters:

- Account number (this is a number that is on their printed statement)
- Surname
- Date of birth

If we find a match for these three pieces of info, the service returns JSON contained a masked version of the user's registered email address (eg. `jo******@gmail.com`) so that the UI can present a message something like "We are going to send your username to `j******@g******.com`. Is that OK?"

Note that the service doesn't actually change anything within their account or send an email (it is purely fetching info so that the user can confirm the next step), so it seems to me that a GET request is the way to go. The question is how to represent it?  It strikes me that `/users` is a reasonable place to start(?), but then what?  Using the URL path, I might end up with something like:

```
/users/accountEmail/accountNumber/123456/surname/Smith/dateOfBirth/25-12-1970
```

This seems icky as, ordinarily, our `/users` URLs contain the username (eg. `/users/john/transactions`), but clearly for this API call we don't actually know who the user is yet.  I'm also not sure it really indicates what the service actually does.  Alternatively, I could use URL query params:

```
/users/accountEmail?accountNumber=123456&surname=Smith&dateOfBirth=25-12-1970
```

This *feels* a bit more natural, but I'm unsure that stringing all those input parameters into the URL is a good idea. Then again, maybe `/users` is the wrong noun.  Maybe it should be like:

```
/accountEmail/...
```

Having said all that, maybe given the service's idempotence, I could actually use a `PUT` request and encode the parameters into the HTTP body.  Not sure about using `PUT` for read-only requests though... it seems a bit like heading down the RPC path. The one nice thing about the `PUT` approach though is that it doesn't log this relatively sensitive user input into any web server logs.

I'd be interested in opinions or hearing what other API developers did in a similar situation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use method GET with sensitive information in URL parameters or in a URL path, because that information can be stored in web server access log files, browser's history, HTTP proxy log files, etc.

Security wise you need to use method POST in this case. In regard of URL to use, I'm not that sure, probably something like /accounts and put all parameters to the request body.

Comment: Yeah, I actually mentioned this specifically when I discussed the PUT option above.  I'm curious, though, why you suggest POST? I'm not actually creating anything... at least with a PUT, there could be an argument that we are still idempotent.

Comment: Because of the security considerations that I've described. Exposing surname, account# and DOB through a URL can eventually lead to an identity theft. That's why the common practice is to send this kind of information in a body over HTTPS.

Comment: Sorry.. I was unclear. I was curious about your suggesting POST (as opposed to PUT).  Or perhaps, you just meant anything other than GET?

Comment: I meant that instead of GET you should use POST when you pass sensitive user's information, so the URL like /users/accountEmail?accountNumber=123456&surname=Smith&dateOfBirth=25-12-1970 with sensitive personal identifiable information (PII) in it should not be used at all.

Comment: As I understand the question, these URLs are calls to a RESTful API. They are used for services to communicate. Using `POST` to get data would not be RESTful.

Comment: Unlike SOAP, REST specification is rather lax and POST can be used even in read-only operations, e.g. see http://rest.elkstein.org/: "POST can also be used for read-only queries, as noted above, when complex parameters are required". I would add - you must use POST when sensitive information needs to be transferred. Would you put a password or an auth token to a URL?

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is what I would use. Logically, the URLS are build following these steps.

**Collection Resource of Users**

The URL

```
GET /users
```

returns a list of *all* users including all user properties.

```
[
  12345: {
    "surname": "Smith",
    "firstname": "John",
    "dateOfBirth": "1970-12-25",
    "accountEmail": "john.smith@example.com"
  },
  6789 : {
    "surname": "Hallow",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "dateOfBirth": "1981-02-15",
    "accountEmail": "jane.hallowh@example.com"
  }
]
```

**Sub-Collection Resource of User Emails**

The URL

```
GET /users/accountEmail
```

returns al list alf *all* emails for all users.

```
[
  12345: {
    "accountEmail": "john.smith@example.com"
  },
    "accountEmail": "jane.hallowh@example.com"
  }
]
```

**Filter this Resource**

The URL

```
GET /users/accountEmail?accountNumber=123456&surname=Smith&dateOfBirth=25-12-1970
```

returns a *filtered* list of emails for the users that match the query parameters.

```
[
  12345: {
    "accountEmail": "john.smith@example.com"
  }
]
```